# What does float' object has no attribute 'replace' when I try locale.atof in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Pandas dataframe series to float. I do `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')` and then `df.idh.apply(locale.atof)`, but it gives me the above mentioned error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`. I assume at some point it's getting something like a NaN, maybe or some other string and it does not recognize it. How do I tell `apply` to skip those?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I don't know how "smart" this is, but I "fixed" it like this, at least for the time being:

```
df.idh = df.idh.astype(str).apply(locale.atof)
```

Please, do let me know the smart answer to this.

Comment: Got love SO. The "I don't know how 'smart' this is" just cracked me. We can all relate to this phrase

Comment: I didn't know how "smart" it is either, but it just helped me and worked, so it is smart.

Answer (score 5):

The problem has to do with null values.  Replace cannot work on numpy nulls.  Your solution doesn't return an error because you convert np.NaN (nulls) into 'nan' and replace can work on the string 'nan'.  The problem is though that you now have 'nan' in your column instead of np.NaN.  So if you run:

```
df[df.idh.isnull()]
```

It would return 0 rows even though you do have nulls in your data.  The following code keeps the np.NaN while running a replace statement on that column.

```
def replace_percent(x):
    try: 
        return x.replace('%', '')
    except AttributeError:
        return np.NaN

df_not.secularism = df_not.secularism.map(replace_percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this alternative solution work for you?

```
csv_nn = df.replace(np.nan, 'null', regex=True)
```